# Could not resolve 'proxyaddress'

Tags: networking, updates, dns

I know there are tons of similar questions but I could not find a solution from all of those. In my case, I have no idea what `proxyaddress` means.

**apt-get update:**

```
Err:1 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily InRelease
  Could not resolve 'proxyaddress'
Err:2 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                     
  Could not resolve 'proxyaddress'
Err:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                             
  Could not resolve 'proxyaddress'
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not resolve 'proxyaddress'
Reading package lists... Done  
W: Failed to fetch http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/InRelease  Could not resolve 'proxyaddress'
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve 'proxyaddress'
W: Failed to fetch http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve 'proxyaddress'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not resolve 'proxyaddress'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**/etc/apt/apt.conf:**

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://proxyaddress:proxyport";
```

**/etc/resolv.conf:**

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# nameserver 8.8.8.8 # tried but did not work.
# nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

**nslookup > server:**

```
Default server: 127.0.1.1
Address: 127.0.1.1#53
```

**netstat -nap:**

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      945/dnsmasq
```

Comment: It likely means you have a (misconfigured) network proxy, either in your `/etc/apt/apt.conf` file (or a file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`) - or system-wide under the desktop's `Settings --> Network` item. FYI the `wily` release is no longer supported.

Comment: `/etc/apt/apt.conf` includes `Acquire::http::Proxy "http://proxyaddress:proxyport";
`. Until recently, updating was working good. Seems like suddenly something happened to `proxyaddress`. What is the problem with it?

Comment: It doesn't look valid to me (even if you had a host called `proxyaddress`, the `proxyport` part needs to be a numeric value AFAIK). I don't see how it could have worked. Regardless, if you *do* need to use an apt proxy, you need to correct the port and/or address - and if you don't - remove the entry.

Comment: I just removed the entry and it worked.